# Question about C++ call virtual function implemented in base from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions, name-lookup, name-hiding

What is wrong with the following code?

```
struct A {
  virtual int hash() const = 0;
  virtual int hash(int x) const = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
  int hash() const final {
    return 10;
  };

  int hash(int x) const override {
    return 10;
  };
};

struct C : public B {
  int hash(int x) const override {
    return x;
  }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  C a;
  std::cout << a.hash() << std::endl;
  std::cout << a.hash(20) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I got compile error with the following error message

```
xx.cc:26:23: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'x' was
      not specified
  std::cout << a.hash() << std::endl;
               ~~~~~~ ^
xx.cc:17:3: note: 'hash' declared here
  int hash(int x) const override {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is name hiding issue. According to the rule of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup),

(emphasis mine)

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, **at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined**.

So `C::hash` hides the name from the base class.

You can apply `using` to introduce the name into the class `C` scope.

```
struct C : public B {
  using B::hash;
  int hash(int x) const override {
    return x;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you have to redefine the overload within the derived class.

```cpp
struct C : public B {
  int hash(int x) const override {
    return x;
  }
  int hash() const override {
    return B::hash();
  }
};
```

Or alternatively call via a reference to B

```cpp
int main() {
  C a;
  B& b = a;
  std::cout << b.hash() << std::endl;
  std::cout << b.hash(20) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```